# Android Ble Api not working on samsung phones properly

Tags: android

I am developing an application which uses Android Ble api. Application has to communicate with BLE firmware hardware device. I am able to communicate with hardware device. 
The strange scene is my application is working perfectly on HP, Sony, htc, Lenovo, etc **except SAMSUNG**. On Samsung device when I enable notification on characteristic, I am not able to receive any data from hardware device (which is working scenario in case of listed devices above).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit the question and clarify what are you asking. For more information read this article: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: okk, first sorry for my poor English. I will take care while asking question from now onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung device not take broad cast directly even other device works for same there for i have done one work around after enable notification on discripter put a speep for few second and read again post that notification broadcast started.

Code snippet :

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```